# issue with post format in wordpress on a custom page template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hey guys so I am trying to have a loop run to get all the post that are within a certain category on a page, for some reason nothing happens though?

Code :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: djequip
*/

get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">

            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php /*query_posts('test');uncategorized*/
                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                 get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                endwhile; endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Let me know if you can help, thanks a ton!

Comment: There's too much "hidden" code here to be able to help.  What's the code in the template part being grabbed through `get_template_part`?

Comment: Oh I didn't really notice that....All I did was just make a template file with this exact code from the home page for grabbing post.

Comment: @cale_b the `get_template_part` is grabbing the post format from the `content` file? I'm trying to reproduce this on the page so I can categorize the post that taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php /* Template Name: TEMPLATE NAME */ ?>
<?php get_header();?>

<?php query_posts('category_name=CATEGORY NAME'); ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is this what you mean?

> the_excerpt

can be changed to

> the_content

Also I'd just like to add that you can put divs in there around the WP PHP.